# How do I know if 2 references are pointing to the same object?

Tags: java, list, doubly-linked-list

I'm making a circular doubly linked list with a header node for school. Since the first actual node (the first one in the list not the header)'s prev goes back to the last node, I can't delete the first node. How can I check if 2 variables are pointing at the same object? I think knowing that is required to delete the first node

Comment: if ( objectA == objectB ) ...

Answer (score 1):

Using `==` on two objects checks if both operands point to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` to compare if two object references point to the same object.

From [*Reference Equality Operators == and !=*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3) in the Java Language Spec:

> *At run time, the result of == is true if the operand values are both null or both refer to the same object or array; otherwise, the result is false.*